# Connect Sails.js to Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mongoatlas

I have been trying to connect my Sails application to the cloud database Mongo Atlas. I got my sails application to lift all the datas are still being store in the local disk. I think I got my connection string corrrect but I'm not sure.

```
// datastores.js 
module.exports.datastores = {
default: {
sails_mongodb: {
      adapter: 'sails-mongo',
      url:'mongodb+srv://tester:JYz43jiRlJxc13ib@cluster1.hmwgtyu.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=cluster1' 
} 
}
```

I tried to set up the connection with my sails application with mongo atlas.
downloaded the adapter : 'sails-mongo'
downloaded: 'mongodb'
changed migrate to : 'alter'
Expectation:
new inputs will be save into mongo atlas database
Result:
inputs are being save into local Sails-disk database